# How to convert to genre, production companies, cast which are JSON column into tibble or df?

Tags: r

https://www.kaggle.com/rounakbanik/the-movies-dataset 
this is the dataset I was using.

I tried the following code in R:

```
m_genres=movies %>% filter(nchar(genres)>2) %>% mutate(js=lapply(genres,fromJSON)) %>% unnest(js) %>% select(id,title,genre=name)%>%group_by(title)%>%mutate(pos = 1:n())%>%ungroup()

m_production_companies=movies %>% filter(nchar(production_companies)>2) %>% mutate(js=lapply(production_companies,fromJSON)) %>% unnest(js) %>% select(id,title,production_company=name)%>%group_by(title)%>%mutate(pos = 1:n())%>%ungroup()
kable(m_genres[1:10,])

#convert json into data frame
genredf=movies %>% filter(nchar(genres)>2) %>% mutate(js=lapply(genres,fromJSON)) %>% unnest(js) %>% select(id,title,genre=name) #Convert JSON format into data frame
slice(genredf)
```

this is the error I got:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  unexpected character "'"; expecting opening string quote (") for key value
```

I'm trying to run a logistic regression. Thus, would like to look at how these small detail affect the movie's budget or production companies.

Comment: There are a few packages already that should make some of what you're writing from scratch easier. I've never used `df2json`, but it doesn't seem to be under active development—last github commit was in 2013. You should be able to do this with [`jsonlite`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/index.html)

Comment: I did jsonlite but get a lot of error such as below: 'm_genres=movies %>% filter(nchar(genres)>2) %>% mutate(js=lapply(genres,fromJSON)) %>% unnest(js) %>% select(id,title,genre=name)%>%group_by(title)%>%mutate(pos = 1:n())%>%ungroup()

kable(m_genres[1:10,])' @camille

Comment: It's much easier to understand your data and error messages if you [edit] them into the post